# How can I set the content md5 when I upload a file to S3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to set the content-MD5 value when I upload a file to S3. I can see the md5 hash string and am passing that into `metadata.setContentMD5()` but after the file is uploaded, I can't see this value in the web console, and I can't retrieve it via java code.

I've come to think that it's likely I'm misunderstanding the goal of the content MD5 get/set methods. Are they used to let the aws server validate that the received file content is consistent with what I am sending? If that's the case then I should send in a value with `setContentMD5(my_md5)` when uploading, but should I then just compare the value of `getETag()` with my calculated md5 hex string when I later try to download that object from S3?

Am I doing something wrong in trying to set this md5 value?

```
String access_key = "myaccesskey";
String secret_key = "mysecretkey";
String bucket_name = "mybucketname";
String destination_key = "md5_test.txt";
String file_path = "C:\\my-text-file.txt";

BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key, secret_key);
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(creds);
client.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion("us-east-1"));

File file = new File(file_path);

ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentType("text/plain");
metadata.setContentLength(file.length());

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] content_bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
String md5 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(DigestUtils.md5(content_bytes)));
metadata.setContentMD5(md5);

PutObjectRequest req = new PutObjectRequest(bucket_name, destination_key, file).withMetadata(metadata);
PutObjectResult result = client.putObject(req);

GetObjectMetadataRequest mreq = new GetObjectMetadataRequest(bucket_name, destination_key);
ObjectMetadata retrieved_metadata = client.getObjectMetadata(mreq);

// I think I expected getContentMD5 below to show the string I passed in
// during the upload, but the below prints "md5:null"
System.out.println("md5:" + retrieved_metadata.getContentMD5());
```

Am I calculating the MD5 string incorrectly? If I pass in a random string, I do get an error message, so it seems like S3 is happy with what I am sending via the above code. And if the MD5 string is correct, why can't I retrieve it later when using the `client.getContentMD5()` method? I understand that ETag should be the MD5 hex string, and I can also calculate that for my uploaded file (and get the same string that S3 calculates), so is it the case that I shouldn't expect the getContentMD5() to ever have a value for a downloaded file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are correct: `getContentMD5()` is just the corresponding getter for `setContentMD5()` [1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#setContentMD5(java.lang.String)). It tells you what the callee side of the request thinks the MD5 hash is. If you want to know what AWS thinks the hash is, you should use the ETag.

> #### getContentMD5
>
> This field represents the base64 encoded 128-bit MD5 digest digest of an object's content as calculated on the caller's side. **The ETag metadata field represents the hex encoded 128-bit MD5 digest as computed by Amazon S3.**
>
> Returns: The base64 encoded MD5 hash of the content for the associated object. **Returns null if the MD5 hash of the content hasn't been set.**

That last part presumably means: *Returns null unless you have previously called `setContentMD5()`*

Comment: Yeah, after playing with it a little more I think it's clearly as you describe. I guess I initially thought that if they were intended to represent the same MD5 hash of the file contents, the MD5 string that you pass in would be identical to the ETag, and it's not, even though they're both based on the same source bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to pass a MD5 string, but if it is provided, Amazon will use it to validate the transmission and make sure what it received is not corrupted.

MD5 is only meaningful during the transmission and its life cycle stops once the transmission is received and validated. To persist it on the server side serves no purpose.

The getter is merely to make the API complete, so you can inspect what you did earlier using the setter.