# Is AWS SDK `PutObjectResult` metadata not holding the content length value?

Tags: java, scala, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am successfully storing objects to S3. As a result of `PutObjectRequest` it returns `PutObjectResult`, which has a `getMetadata()` method. However, the metadata it returns is holding some values and misses others that I would expect to be there. In particular it misses the content length value, though it is explicitly assigned to `PutObjectRequest`.

For instance, this sample code:

```
  val client: AmazonS3 = ???

  val contentBytes = "Test content".getBytes
  val inputStream: InputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes)

  val metadata = new ObjectMetadata
  metadata.setContentLength(contentBytes.length)

  val putRequest = new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", "key", inputStream, metadata)
    .withStorageClass(StorageClass.valueOf("ReducedRedundancy"))

  val putObjectResult = client.putObject(putRequest)

  println(s"Storage class: ${putObjectResult.getMetadata.getStorageClass}; Length: ${putObjectResult.getMetadata.getContentLength}")
```

would return the following: **Storage class: REDUCED_REDUNDANCY; Length: 0**

Is it a bug, am I doing something wrong, or is it expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I think content-length of request and response are different things.

Run the application in DEBUG mode and you will see following results,

put following sbt log4j dependency in `build.sbt` and log config in `src/main/resources/log4j.properties`,

```
libraryDependencies += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17"
```

log config

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, stdout

## Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Then on your request you can clearly see the content-length being 12,

```
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG request:1137 - Sending Request: PUT https://samsa-repo.s3.amazonaws.com /test-bytes Headers: (User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.11.109 Mac_OS_X/10.11.6 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.111-b14/1.8.0_111 scala/2.11.8, amz-sdk-invocation-id: ad0dec57-4d52-9855-4d4b-b802306cd610, Content-Length: 12, x-amz-storage-class: REDUCED_REDUNDANCY, Content-Type: application/octet-stream, ) 
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG AWS4Signer:33 - AWS4 Canonical Request: '"PUT
/test-bytes

amz-sdk-invocation-id:ad0dec57-4d52-9855-4d4b-b802306cd610
amz-sdk-retry:0/0/500
content-length:12
content-type:application/octet-stream
host:samsa-repo.s3.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-sdk-java/1.11.109 Mac_OS_X/10.11.6 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.111-b14/1.8.0_111 scala/2.11.8
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:20170531T221640Z
x-amz-security-token:"i am hiding it"
x-amz-storage-class:REDUCED_REDUNDANCY
```

While on the response, you will see following result with http response code and etag etc. Since it has no content other than header information content-length has to be `0`.

```
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "x-amz-id-2: 3DpsdWzL97tHmVBq4xfuqQtHBzaeGjhcsTBmqc8cZWjcZYGWkjnGOgrYaqfTqZo5UygLd3tLEPE=[\r][\n]"
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "x-amz-request-id: 47FCD67C6CBAC015[\r][\n]"
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Wed, 31 May 2017 22:16:41 GMT[\r][\n]"
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "ETag: "8bfa8e0684108f419933a5995264d150"[\r][\n]"
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "x-amz-storage-class: REDUCED_REDUNDANCY[\r][\n]"
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: AmazonS3[\r][\n]"
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG headers:124 - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 << x-amz-id-2: 3DpsdWzL97tHmVBq4xfuqQtHBzaeGjhcsTBmqc8cZWjcZYGWkjnGOgrYaqfTqZo5UygLd3tLEPE=
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 << x-amz-request-id: 47FCD67C6CBAC015
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Wed, 31 May 2017 22:16:41 GMT
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 << ETag: "8bfa8e0684108f419933a5995264d150"
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 << x-amz-storage-class: REDUCED_REDUNDANCY
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 0
2017-05-31 15:16:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 << Server: AmazonS3
```

### references

see Example 1: Upload an Object, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

Comment: Seems like you nailed it.  Entirely unrelated, it's very troubling that the SDK sends no `Content-MD5` header and uses `x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD`.  That seems wrong, twice -- both available mechanisms for validating that the upload arrives at S3 intact are being bypassed.  I haven't worked with the Java SDK (I wrote my own libs, not in Java) but this is a surprise.  Are those options you have to enable, or does it just... not do that unless you do it manually?

Comment: @prayagupd If I understand you right the content-length header is `0` because it is a characteristic of `PutObjectResult` (i.e. the response), which carries no content. Perhaps you are right, but then the logic is contradictory: the `PutObjectResult` carries the storage-class data, which was part of the request and shouldn't be in the result either (just as content-length isn't).

Comment: @prayagupd Also, the description of `PutObjectResult` says: "Use this class to access information about the new object created from the putObject request...". Hence, when `getMetadata()` returns an `ObjectMetadata` I assume it should have the data about the object stored with the `PutObjectRequest`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot `Content-MD5` header is set on file to be uploaded to s3 by the api itself but not on the `InputStream`. [API Code -> here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L1600). But `Content-MD5` can be explicitly set using `metadata.setContentMD5(new String(Base64.getEncoder.encode(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(content.getBytes()))))`. Throws `<Code>BadDigest</Code>` error when I set wrong `Content-MD5` header

Comment: @SergioPelin The API looks weird to me. For example, a request has a `Content-MD5` header in it but the response api does not have it as `response.getMetadata.getContentMD5` gives `null`. So, [I guess those are useless 16th century getters/setters only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35422109/432903), not necessarily API will have those in response headers. You can check what to expect on response at Response section of this doc - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html Thats what confusing is.

Comment: @prayagupd You are right about SDK API and this is exactly my point. If it holds some old stuff (e.g. for compatibility) I would expect this to be marked as deprecated. If it isn't, it is supposed to work, according to what its interface and documentation says. I really appreciate your response, but I wouldn't like to take the question/answer from the context of AWS SDK to REST API.